# Relation between grid-template-areas and grid-template columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I am new to coding and don't seem to understand the CSS Grid model correctly.
In the code below the grid is divided into 3 grid-template-columns (300px each) but then there are 8 units per row in the grid-template-areas (for example: hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd) and not 3 which does not make sense to me. Can somebody please help me understand why the number of units in the grid-template-area is not the same as the number of columns? (so it would be "hd hd hd" if there are 3 columns). What is their relation?

```
.container {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px;
    grid-template-rows: 250px 600px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd"
    "sd sd sd main main main main main"
    "ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft";
}
```

Comment: for you better understanding and clearing concept check this https://bitsofco.de/understanding-the-difference-between-grid-template-and-grid-auto/.

Comment: Where did you get this code? Have to checked to see what happens when you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining your template-areas you defined a grid with 8x3 items. By default those items will have an auto width and and auto height like below:

```css
.container {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd"
    "sd sd sd main main main main main"
    "ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft";
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

The height will be 0 since there is no content and the width of your container will be splitted equally on the 8 columns.

If you add template-columns/rows you will explicitely define the width/height of the grid tracks. By defining only 3 numbers inside `grid-template-columns` you will define a width for only the first 3 columns and the other one will remain `auto`. Same logic with `grid-template-rows`

```css
.container {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 60px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd"
    "sd sd sd main main main main main"
    "ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft";
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

If I consider the above code, you will have `50px 50px 50px auto auto auto auto auto` for the columns and `50px 60px auto` for the rows.

---

To be more accurate, here is the description for the sepcification:

> The size of the explicit grid is determined **by the larger of the number of rows/columns** defined by `grid-template-areas` and the number of rows/columns sized by `grid-template-rows`/`grid-template-columns`. Any rows/columns defined by `grid-template-areas` but not sized by `grid-template-rows`/`grid-template-columns` take their size from the `grid-auto-rows`/`grid-auto-columns` properties. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#explicit-grids)</sup>

As you can clearly see, we are falling into the case where we have rows/columns not sized by `grid-template-rows`/`grid-template-columns` so their size will be defined by `grid-auto-rows`/`grid-auto-columns`  where the default valus is set to `auto`

You can adjust the value to get a different result:

```css
.container {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px 60px;
    grid-auto-columns:10px;
    grid-auto-rows:20px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "hd hd hd hd hd hd hd hd"
    "sd sd sd main main main main main"
    "ft ft ft ft ft ft ft ft";
    border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

The above code will give use `50px 50px 50px 10px 10px 10px 10px 10px` for the columns and `50px 60px 20px` for the rows.

Comment: Thank you very much!
It still doesn't seem like good practice to me but I understood it thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

The first three `hd` columns will have a width of 300px.

The remaining five `hd` columns will default to content-width (`auto`).

The `grid-template-columns` property sets the width of columns sequentially. So the first three columns are 300px wide.

The remaining `hd` columns have no corresponding width set in `grid-template-columns`, so they are, essentially, `width: auto`. More specifically, columns defined in `grid-template-areas`, but not sized by `grid-template-columns`, [are governed by `grid-auto-columns`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#explicit-grids), who's default setting is `auto`.